# Synonym request for 'custom tags'

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

Currently I see three tags [custom-tag](/questions/tagged/custom-tag), [custom-tags](/questions/tagged/custom-tags) and [customtags](/questions/tagged/customtags). I propose these to be merged to [custom-tags](/questions/tagged/custom-tags).

Answer (score 1):

This tag is way too ambiguous; it should just be burned, all of them. Just browsing through the already incredibly short list of questions, I'm seeing it being used for JSP, Java, Struts, ColdFusion, Ruby on Rails, and HTML. Though the only tag wiki (on [custom-tags](/questions/tagged/custom-tags)) seems to indicate the tag is strictly for JSP. I don't really see it adding any value to the questions it is on.

Comment: I disagree; while the questions about ruby and html just address the *parsing* of custom tags, those addressing jsp, java and struts target a very precise java technology.

Comment: @guido: Then they need a different tag. That doesn't make the current tag any less ambiguous.

Comment: yes that's what I mean, the customtags tag should be used, as told in its description, just on java/jsp questions (and synonyms merged). Should be replaced with something more generic (ie: parsing) elsewhere.

Comment: That doesn't eliminate the problem of people continuing to use the tag. The term "custom tags" may mean something specific in JSP, but the phrase "custom tags" means a larger variety of things across many other languages. If you really need a custom-tags tag, then it should be somehow JSP-specific if it only applies to JSP questions. Not even half the questions tagged with these appear to be related to JSP. Django does this with [tag:django-custom-tags].

Comment: Out of java/jsp context, we can consider custom-tags easily as general as "tag-based meta language"; while in-context, we can consider java as a superset of jsp, and jsp as a superset of the (jsp) custom-tags questions. Unfortunately custom tags is a very bad name for this technology but nevertheless is how the developers commonly refer to that. Maybe jsp-tag-library would be better? For sure, but I doubt people would use it